# Integrate sass on macOS and Jenkins

Tags: ruby, jenkins, rubygems, sass

I have installed sass on my mac build agent. Attach the approve: here is output from my machine

```
ep@ep2:~$ sass -v
Sass 3.3.8 (Maptastic Maple)
ep@ep2:~$ sass --help
Usage: sass [options] [INPUT] [OUTPUT]

Description:
Converts SCSS or Sass files to CSS.

Options:
-s, --stdin                      Read input from standard input instead of an input file
    --trace                      Show a full traceback on error
    --unix-newlines              Use Unix-style newlines in written files.
    --scss                       Use the CSS-superset SCSS syntax.
    --watch                      Watch files or directories for changes.
                                 The location of the generated CSS can be set using a colon:
                                   sass --watch input.sass:output.css
                                   sass --watch input-dir:output-dir
    --update                     Compile files or directories to CSS.
                                 Locations are set like --watch.
```

And write it to bash_profile:

```
 Users/ep/.rvm/bin:~/.gem/ruby/1.8/bin
```

When i try to execute my job in jenkins it failed with

```
14:18:34     /bin/sh -c sass\ -f\ -C\ ${INPUT_FILE_PATH}\ ${DERIVED_FILES_DIR}/${INPUT_FILE_BASE}.css
14:18:34 /bin/sh: sass: command not found
14:18:34 Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 127
```

I made a little investigation and have added this property to jenkins nodes propey and checked the user, the user run script it's the same from whom i installed gem.

How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Probably the tool `sass` is not in the shell PATH when Jenkins executes your build script.

You should either:

- run the tool by providing the full path to it or
- modify the PATH environment variable to include the installation directory of the tool.

Please note that modifying PATH by changing shell initialization file is often the wrong way to do it with Jenkins. When Jenkins executes a shell, it is not an interactive login shell and those often skip initialization files like .profile or .bashrc or bash_profile. The details can be found in your shell man page.

It is better to add the PATH to Jenkins configuration, either to master configuration (if the job executes on master) or slave configuration (if the job executes on a slave). In the configuration check the box titled "Environment variables" and add name and value for required environment variables.

It might not be a bad idea to begin build scripts with command `env` which prints all environments variables. Often it makes debugging problems like this a lot easier.